# how to get dell laptop display on tv?

Tags: display

my dell laptop screen is damaged. I installed ubuntu 12.04.01 with tv monitor connected. After rebooting nothing is displayed on tv monitor, is any graphic driver missing from the installation?

edit - ( captured from tv monitor display boot mode)
device info from BIOS 
Video Controller  - Intel 915M Graphics
Video BIOS version - 1219
Video Memory - 8 MB

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the TV via HDMI, then select it via the display applet in system settings.

Comment: nothing is seen on the tv monitor after rebooting, so cannot select system settings

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps =>

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 after booting Ubuntu to activate the console display
2. Connect the new display monitor or TV
3. press Ctrl + Alt + F7, and the GUI should come up on the new display (TV/monitor) immediately

Unless something is wrong with your connection or drivers or setup, I think it should work without any reboot or logout.